# apache2 web server index.html problems

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am having a problem with document root. The onlt way I can get to my index.html is by specifying
http://mysite.com/index.html , is there a way to have it automatically redirected to index.html with http://mysite.com ?

ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to your host configuration. This basically tell the server what files to look for if no file is specifed in the request.

In your case this could work:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```